# Getting the Novell Username in a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, novell

I'm currently developing a small application in WPF for us at work though I'm not a professional software engineer, so this might be obvious. However, I cannot find an answer to my question (maybe I used the wrong keywords)
Anyway, our computers are setup so that we need to log on through Novell Client for Windows. The password from the Novell account is synced with the Windows 'Administrator' account. Thus, effectively, everyone is Administrator on his machine. Novell is used to authenticate against a local Fileserver.

The problem now is, when I try to get the Username in my application using Environment.Username or any other method, I will only ever get 'Administrator' as the logged in user.

Question: How can I get the Novell username from my WPF application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late with the answer but I believe you will find the name of the current user logged into Netware or NDS in the windows registry if you do a search.